# Error while compiling tossim in tiny OS

Tags: operating-system, tinyos

When I try to compile TOSSIM in tiny OS v-2.0.2 , this is the error that it is giving me:

```
# make micaz sim 

Makefile:2: /opt/tinyos-2.1.0/support/make/Makerules: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/opt/tinyos-2.1.0/support/make/Makerules'.  Stop.
```

How to remove this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run a `./configure` ? This is usually the config script used by make files,  but sometimes people use strange build systems so I'd look around in the project's root directory for something else relating to configuring or installing.  There should also be a text file called 'INSTALL' which helps.

The usual build commands are:

```
./configure 
make
make install clean
```